# Foreach com duas listas do bd. blade do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Li alguns artigos e vi desta maneira, porém não está correto dando o seguinte erro:

> (1/1) ErrorException  Undefined offset: 1

```
@foreach($palpites, $confrontos) as ($p, $c))
  <tr>    
    <td> {{ $p->diadojogo}} </td>
    <td> {{ $p->timea }} </td>
    <td> {{ $c->diadojogo}} </td>
    <td> {{ $c->resultado}} </td>      
  </tr>    
@endforeach
```

Comment: Quais artigos você leu? Buscou na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable)? Nela nem consta esta sintaxe que utilizou.

Comment: Poste o artigo aonde o `foreach` faz a interação em duas listas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar desta forma, acredito que ira funcionar para a sua situação:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>coluna1P</th>
            <th>coluna2P</th>
            <th>coluna1C</th>
            <th>coluna2C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($palpites as $index => $palpite)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $palpite['diajogo'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ $palpite['timea'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ $confrontos[$index]['diajogo'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ $confrontos[$index]['resultado'] }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Acredito que só não ira funcionar se as quantidades de palpites e confrontos não forem a mesma.

Comment: O seu codigo dá erro. tanto uma parte quanto a outra isolada.
@ foreach($palpites as $index => $palpite)
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
  <tr>

    <td> {{ $palpite['diadojogo'] }} </td>
    <td> {{ $palpite['timea'] }} </td>
  
      
    

  </tr>

  @ endforeach

@ foreach($palpites as $index => $palpite)
        <tr>
           
            <td> {{ $confrontos[$index]['diajogo'] }} </td>
            <td> {{ $confrontos[$index]['resultado'] }} </td>
        </tr>
    @ endforeach

Comment: O erro ocorre devido eu estar trabalhando com arrays e você está tentando acessar como objeto.